# How can I allow moving cursor in macOS TextField (SwiftUI) like on iOS?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I found a weird behavior when testing `TextField` with SwiftUI on macOS, that does not exist on iOS.

Basically when a TextField has a fixed width and contains more text than it can display (aka it has an overflow), on iOS the user can move the cursor on the left/right (thus "scrolling" the text horizontally except there's no scrollbar) to see any portion of the text they want to display.

However on macOS, the exact same code doesn't allow the user to "scroll" horizontally and you can only see the first few characters of what you typed, no matter where your cursor is.

Here is a minimal code showing this behavior and a screen record of how it (doesn't) work:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @State var value = ""

    var body: some View {       
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $value)
//                .fixedSize()
                .frame(width: 150)
//                .fixedSize()
            Text(value)
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 200, minHeight: 100)
    }
}
```

https://streamable.com/xj4sx8

So my question is: how can I fix my TextField width without having that kind of odd UI bug?

Comment: I also experience this (not sure about on the beta though). One option is in the next version to use multi line TextField

Comment: I opted for wrapping an `NSTextView` in `NSViewRepresentable`